# Representing "issues" in a distributed VCS

Tags: git, issue-tracking

I'm tired of all those issue tracking systems that can only be used online or via email, so I've been looking at keeping track of issues in a database that can be replicated and merged (so it can be used offline).

To make my life easier, I figured I should reuse existing tools using such a database, and Git came to mind.  But for it to work well, it's important that the "merges" don't generate too many conflicts, i.e. that Git's built-in algorithms to merge branches be used wisely.

As of now, I figured that the various messages in a given issue shouldn't be kept in files (keeping them all in a single file would lead to conflicts in that file, and keeping them in separate files would lead to difficulty keeping them ordered) but should instead be stored in the commit-messages, so there can't be a conflict because of those messages and `git log <issue-dir>` will naturally show me the messages in the right order.

But the problem now is that I need to make sure the commit message is associated with the right "issue directory" (where I keep the rest of the data, i.e. mostly the state of the issue).  For that I need to make sure the commit modifies some file in that directory, but if the new message doesn't affect the state of the issue, there might not be any file that needs to be changed, so I'd have to articifically modify a file, which brings back the risk of introducing a conflict.  Any idea how to tell Git that an "empty commit" should be associated with a particular subdirectory?

Comment: Version control and issue tracking are usually two different things (though it's not unheard of to have a bug tracker integrated with VCS).  Have you looked at something like BitBucket, which has both issue tracking and VCS, and where it's very easy to assign issues to commits?

Comment: I'm not using Git as a version control system, I'm just using it internally to the issue tracking as a "replicable&mergeable database engine".  I.e. I store the issues in Git, but those issues can be about anything (e.g. something stored in some other Git repository, but not necessarily).

Comment: You might want to check ticketing built into fossil scm: https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/help?cmd=ticket https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/bugtheory.wiki . I have not used it myself, but they seem to have some experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did not find a clean way to link an empty commit's message with a particular directory, other than by adding some dummy file which was just too ugly for my taste.

But I ended up solving a slightly different problem: instead of having a separate *directory* per bug, I placed every bug in its own *branch*.  This way, there's no need to perform any gymnastics to match commit messages to particular bugs.   Additionally, that avoids artificially interleaving commit messages from different bugs, and makes it possible to `git merge` bugs, or to share some subset of bugs between different bug databases.

If interested, I've put my code up at https://gitlab.com/monnier/bugit

Answer (score 0):

There are several bug trackers that work inside of your version control; Bugs Everywhere is the one that comes to mind. With Bugs Everywhere you put your bug reports in the same repository as the code. Each bug report is a separate file, and is typically edited with the be command line program. This works very naturally with the branching you're already doing in your repository, because you can check out a branch and see the status of all the bugs at that point in time.

Storing the bug reports in commit message seems like a poor fit. How do you update a bug? You can't update a commit message without invalidating every following commit.

I don't think you can prevent merge conflicts with your design; you'll have to force whoever detects the merge conflict to rebase their changes to the bug before pushing.

Comment: My repository only contains bug tracking information and nothing else.  Indeed, by keeping the messages as commit messages, I make it impossible to update a message, but not impossible to update a bug (the bug's description is made of a sequence of messages, each one corresponding to a commit).    Since merge conflicts only come from file operations, they can't come from the messages stored in the commit messages.  Of course, I still need to store files (basically to keep track of the bug's status), so there is still a possibility of conflict.

Comment: Merge conflicts can come from non-file operations as well. If I clone your repository and then we both add a comment to the same bug, then when I push my comment back there will be a merge conflict. I suppose for comments it doesn't matter much, since you can just rebase on behalf of the user; the order of the comments doesn't matter much. On the other hand, if we both change some metadata about the bug, then an automatic rebase could be quite surprising. BE solves this by putting all of the content in files, including the comments; the user merges at the same time they merge the source files.

Comment: No, that's not a merge conflict, that's just a merge: i.e. indeed the push will fail because it's not a "fast-forward", so I'll have to merge the other changes (i.e. the earlier comment), but that merge will not generate any conflict; and after that I can push.  No need for rebase.